# Relative clauses vs. comma

Tags: relative-clauses

The following sentence with a relative clause is correct:

> I like the girl that lives next door.

Is it possible to substitute a relative clause `who/that/which` with the clause and a comma? For example:

> I like the girl, she lives next door.

Comment: It's an unlikely orthography. Most people would say/write *I like the girl **who** lives next door,* but if you don't combine the two elements like that, all you've really got is ***two sentences.*** Which would normally be separated by a full stop, not a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I like the girl who/that lives next door.

Is indeed a sentence with a relative clause.

If you try to break it down into a sentence and a clause you get two complete separate sentences separated by a full stop:

- I like the girl.
- The girl lives next door.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use participial clause as a postmodifier. 'I like the girl living next door'.